# CSS: How to custom the header rows' background separated by odd and even?

Tags: html, css, html-table

In **CSS** html table style design, we can customize the header row's font color by `color`, and background by `background-color` in `thead`. Here is the example.

```css
thead {
    color: #555555;
    background-color: #f7f8f9;
}
```

My confusion is whether we can customize the background of the header one in a separated manner or not. Like the **odd** ones in **blue**, and **even** ones in **red**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, the important parts are:

```
    th:nth-child(odd) { background-color: blue; }
    th:nth-child(even) { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
 th:nth-child(odd) { background-color: blue; }
 th:nth-child(even) { background-color: red; }  
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem</td>
      <td>ipsum</td>
      <td>amet</td>
      <td>jabar</td>
      <td>foobar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Taken from https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, That's exactly what I want. (❁´◡`❁)

Answer (score 0):

`thead` is actually a row in HTML table. So you can't access to `tr` and `td` with this selector in CSS.

On the other hand, if you want to make the rows' background as striped, you can use CSS3's `:nth-of-type(even)` and `:nth-of-type(odd) selectors` for this.

HTML:

```
<table >
   <thead>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
   </thead>
   <tr>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #888;
}

tr:nth-of-type(odd){
   background-color: #00f;
}

thead, tr:nth-of-type(even){
   background-color: #f00;
}
```

Here is the example: https://codepen.io/sundowatch/pen/MWaQqym

Comment: Thank you, but the project I work on requires customization on **columns' background** as striped. Is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to solve this problem. Note while doing this you need to add the jQuery script. If you don't already have it you can download it from NuGet if you're using Visual Studio.

**HTML CODE:**

```
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Even</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Odd
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Even</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Odd</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Even</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**THE CSS:**

```
  .zebra {
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
    }

    .zebra1 {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
```

**THE JAVASCRIPT:**

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("tr:even").addClass("zebra1"); //This code makes gives all even rows in the table the class of zebra1
        $("tr:odd").addClass("zebra"); //This code makes all the odd rows in the table the class of zebra
    });
```

This jQuery makes attaches the classes of zebra and zebra1 to the odd and even rows of the table respectively.